# Изменить параметры в UDP socket PHP

Tags: php, сокет, udp, cisco

При посылке UDP пакета через socket требуется изменить внутренние параметры
Version
Type
Pap/Chap
Rsv
UserIp
AttrNum

На картинке слева верный вариант, справа не верный... все почему то добавляется в тело, не меняя параметров.

Использую обычный socket php
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему вы это называете "внутренние параметры". в протоколе UDP нет указанных вами полей. Это поля некого прикладного уровня, находящегося по верх udp и к параметрам сокета точно никакого отношения не имеющие. С точки зрения UDP это все область пользовательских данных и если в ней что то не так надо смотреть код который это формирует и который вы в вопросе почему то не привели

Comment: И на картинке слева некий двоичный пакет правильно расшифровываемый как пакет некого протокола. А вот справа у вас в пакете не двоичные данные а просто текст

Comment: Кода как такового нету, мне просто дали вырезку из WireShark и сказали что бы работало параметры должны совпадать. А я даже не знаю с чего начать... просто использовать socket не выходит, может что другое ?

Comment: а что должно работать, если кода нет ? А использовать надо в любом случае socket, других способов работы с сетью не существует. просто область данных надо сформировать в правильном формате

Comment: И wireshark как единственным источником информации пользоваться нельзя. нужно для начала узнать что это за протокол и найти его полное техническое описание, RFC например

Comment: Я имею в виду на что опираться при формировании пакета для отсылки? в каком виде, нужно ли паковать или распаковывать что либо. В сторону каких команд смотреть

Comment: протокол двоичный, так что да, наверняка надо будет упаковывать и для этого есть только одна функция `pack()`